# wonderlandads.com popup virus

Tags: windows, virus, windows-10

### Problem

As for [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128957/removal-of-the-wonderlandads-com-pop-up-virus) or [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129057/why-does-chrome-open-links-from-wonderlandads-com-on-scrolling) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734490/chrome-opens-wonderlands-link-on-scrolling), my computer has been infected to this sh-t and my browsers open an annoying pop-up on every single click to whatever web page I am visiting and this is repeated really unlimited times, getting me more and more nervous.

It was just Google Chrome ( 47.0.2526.106 m ), but now I have it on Opera ( 34.0.2036.25 ) too, and I think it will go through the Firefox, IE, ... soon.

### Environment

- Windows 10 x64 Enterprise (1151) Build 10586.29

### My efforts

- Used Chrome's `Help > Report and issue` menu to report it to the Google.
- Used the [Chrome Cleanup Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) to remove any problems at the very first moment (just before my opera get infected too).
- Using the tool, I noticed that the `exe` file ( Chrome Cleanup Tool ) gets deleted automatically right after usage and so I added an audit on the file for deletion to suspect what process deletes the `chrome_cleanup_tool.exe` file using `Security` section under `Windows Logs` in `Windows Even Viewr`. The answer was:

  ```
  Object:
      Object Server:          Security
      Object Type:            File
      Object Name:            C:\Users\{my-user-name}\Downloads\chrome_cleanup_tool.exe
      Handle ID:              0x2c
      Resource Attributes:    S:AI

  Process Information:
      Process ID:             0x179c
      Process Name:           C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe

  Access Request Information:
      Accesses:               DELETE
      Access Mask:            0x10000
  ```

  So I am almost sure that my windows has been infected with virus and there is nothing to do with Chrome, Opera, ...

### My question

How can I remove the infection from my computer?

Comment: Trix - if your machine has been infected, and you don't have a solution from your antivirus vendor, the solution is to completely wipe it and start from scratch. Your post here is off topic as we don't provide av guidance.

Comment: Trix - after your edit. Virus removal guidance is off topic here. Check out guidance on any of the antivirus vendors sites. Google will find you a range of options.

Comment: Thanks for putting my question on hold. could u please tell me whats the problem? I just wanted to know if somebody else has the same issue and any workarounds

Comment: Not a problem, just not on topic here.

Comment: @Trix Unfortunately, this question is off-topic. We are not a malware removal forum.